# CSS grid background image full size

Tags: html, css

Hello how can I make half1/half2 background image to start at the end of the bootstrap navbar and end at the bottom of the page making no side scroll bar available on any resolution.
I tried with different methods,like making the body and html 100% height and play with content and navbar % or using the vh measure unit,I cant figure it out what is the issue,thank you.

```
Github: https://github.com/cotrutatiberiu/WW2
Site: https://cotrutatiberiu.github.io/WW2/nations/nations/us.html
Html path: WW2/nations/nations/us.html
Css path: WW2/css/nationscss/us.css
```

PS:Grid might be broken,i'm learning it

Answer (score 0):

it is a little bit hard, because your layout not support it. But if you take both images and use some photo editor (photoshop or something) to merge them to only one image, it can help. Than you will use your new image on `body background-image` and use `background-size: cover;`. Be careful, other elements have to have transparent `background`.

Comment: Yeah I know I kinda complicated things,thank you for the tip tho.